# Specify Description-Content-Type in Pypi upload for markdown README

Tags: python, markdown, pypi

According to [PyPA Specifications](https://packaging.python.org/specifications/#description-content-type) it should be possible to use markdown formatted README files when uploading to Pypi.

What I don't quite understand is where to put this configuration line. I suspect it has to be PKG-INFO but a) it doesn't work (I added it manually after `setup.py dist`) and b) I don't think it's intended to be added manually.

What I also did is to add the README.md in the Manifest.in

```
include README.md
```

and specify it in setup.cfg:

```
[metadata]
description-file = README.md
```

You can have a look at my repo [here](https://github.com/liip/html2kirby).

However, there's nothing being displayed on pypi, as if there was no README.

I am fully aware that RST is the recommended way and most stuff on the web is about how to convert MD to RST, which didn't work for me neither (possibly due to incompatible RST versions). According to [this blog post](http://peterdowns.com/posts/first-time-with-pypi.html) and mentionned [PyPA Specifications](https://packaging.python.org/specifications/#description-content-type) it should be possible to use markdown and I would very much like to do that.

Comment: How does this not work? What were you expecting that you didn't get?

Comment: Note that the PyPA Specification only applies to the new pypi.org, not the legacy pypi.python.org. See [Migrating to PyPI.org](https://packaging.python.org/guides/migrating-to-pypi-org/) for more info. As I understand it, there has never been, and never will be Markdown support with the legacy system.

Comment: Off-topic, but fyi, looking at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/html2kirby/0.1 I note that your generic link in the beginning to Kirbytext instead links to the `#links` fragment within the page: https://getkirby.com/docs/content/text#links

Comment: I have fixed my answer, now tested and working

Answer (score 0):

**Brief:** (fixed)

**`long-description-content-type = text/markdown`**

**UPDATE**

The [prb](https://docs.openstack.org/pbr/latest/index.html) description isn't correct

Checkout my project as reference. On [test.pypi](https://test.pypi.org/project/wexpect/2.3.6.dev22/) and the source on [github](https://github.com/raczben/wexpect/blob/b76e32725e4b8b4194eeedf8c2fbcf17c6fe0bc9/setup.cfg).